# Zend - Combine referenceMaps with easyother

Tags: php, zend-framework, models, zend-db-table

In my current project I'm working with '**referenceMap**'s and '**dependentTables**'. Everything is working like I wanted except from the problem that I need to combine two finders with each other. I couldn't find a proper solution, so thats where you guys kick in to hopefully have the right solution.

**IndexController**

```
$accountsTable  = new Module_Model_Languages();

$accountsRowset = $accountsTable->find(Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Locale'));
$user1234       = $accountsRowset->current();

$bugsAssignedToPrints  = $user1234->findModule_Model_ModulesPagesContentsPrintsViaModule_Model_ModulesPagesContentsMultilingual()->toArray();

$bugsAssignedToContent = $user1234->findModule_Model_ModulesPagesContentsViaModule_Model_ModulesPagesContentsMultilingual()->toArray();

// Dumping results       
Zend_Debug::dump($bugsAssignedToPrints);
Zend_Debug::dump($bugsAssignedToContent);
```

---

Its all about the two variables **$bugsAssignedToPrints** and **$bugsAssignedToContent**. I dont want to arrays with results, but combine them as one array. The Model classes can be found via Pastebin. Sorry for my bad explanation... its the best I could do.

[Model - Languages.php](http://pastebin.com/xZc9X5K9)

[Model - ModulesPagesContentsMultilingual.php](http://pastebin.com/Yi8dYx6j)

P.S.: I wasn't allowed to post all the files from Pastebin duo to my new user account. But I think these two are the most important.

Thanks!